# How do you summarize row data in sybase table

Tags: sql, sybase

I have this table in sybase:

```
Date                File_name   File_Size   customer    Id
1/1/205 11:00:00    temp.csv    100000      ESPN        1111
1/1/205 11:10:00    temp.csv    200000      ESPN        1122
1/1/205 11:20:00    temp.csv    400000      ESPN        1456
1/1/205 11:30:00    temp.csv    400000      ESPN        2345
1/2/205 11:00:00    llc.csv     100000      LLC         445
1/2/205 11:10:00    llc1.txt    200000      LLC         677
1/2/205 11:20:00    dtt.txt     500000      LLC         76
1/2/205 11:30:00    jpp.txt     400000      LLC         666
```

I need to come up with a query to summarize this data by day which will be month/day/Year.

```
Date        total_file_size number_of_unique_customers number_unique_id
1/1/2015    110,000         1                          4
1/2/2015    120,000         1                          4
```

How would I do this in sql query? I tried this:

```
select convert(varchar,arrived_at,110) as Date 
   sum(File_Size), 
   count(distinct(customer)), 
   count(distinct(id)) 
group by Date
```

Does not seem to be working, any ideas?

Comment: what error you have ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
select 
   convert(varchar,arrived_at,110) as Date,
   SUM(File_Size), 
   count(distinct customer) as number_of_unique_customers, 
   count(distinct id ) as number_unique_id
group by convert(varchar,arrived_at,110)
```

Comment: I need to group it by date, not file_name

Comment: Glad that solve it for you. Hope downvoter also check the fix.